# Handle pending intents and notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

**THE SCENARIO**

---

I rise a notification from a background service. It launch the notification when there is no activities bound to. When the user tap the notification the code inside the **Activity_A** reads the action from the `getIntent();` now I know what to do with a given action. At this point everything goes ok. After read the action it start and activity for result, it starts the **Activity_B**, so **Activity_A** is sent to background and destroyed(I set my phone to kill activities when user leaves them), user is doing some in **Activity_B**  and then press back, when **Activity_A** restores, I read the same intent action as the beginning and enter in crazy loop where i can not leave the **Activity_B**.

**WHAT I'M LOOKING?**

---

I want to clear the action inside the starter intent.
This will definitely help because after receiving the action which was given by a PendingIntent through a notification, the system can destroy and recreate the **Activity_A** ignoring the consumed action.

Comment: I suggest that you consider combining Activity_A and Activity_B into one activity. "I want to clear the action inside the starter intent" -- that is read-only, sorry. You should be able to set a flag in the saved instance state for Activity_A to indicate that you already started Activity_B, but having just one activity would be more stable IMHO.

Comment: Is this a backstack problem? A foreground service? Can you post some code?

Comment: @commonsware I had the suspect it was read only, but I was not sure about that, now is more clear. About combining the two activities I also thinks its a better idea, since it can reduce the life cycles changes. Previously I had all **Activity_B** in a fragment but I switch to a no toolbar activity to get more screen real estate.

Comment: @Pomagranite I think it was a lack of experience problem.

Comment: @AlexSanchez Several issues here. Pending intent is a permission thing, like me handing you a key to my car and say here drive it. Pending intent is an intent passed to another app and saying here you run this intent because you have permission.

Comment: @AlexSanchez Service usually does not have User Interface. Service does not run on the UI thread. Backstack is when you launch an intent and then press back button on the device.